# Which is a better way to layout if() { try {} catch {} }?

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement, try-catch

I have a layout that when I try to make a specific kind of query to MySQL (insert, update or select)

```
Method()
{
    Connect();

    if ( i == 1)
    {
        try 
        {
            // Query Db...
        }
        catch {}
        finally 
        {
            // Close Connection.
        }
    }
    else if ( i == 2)
    {
        // More try/catch...
    }
}
```

However i was wondering if this way was better?

```
Method()
{
    Connect();
    try
    {
        if ( i == 1)
        {
            // Query Db...
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            // Query Db...
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        // Close Connection
    }
}
```

Is there any real difference or benefit to one or another?

Comment: What sort of exceptions are thrown from your queries?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead just `MySqlException`.

Comment: What I meant was ... why do you need to catch exceptions? Perhaps dealing with the underlying cause of the exception is a starter to cleaning up the code.

Comment: at the moment this application is still in it's early development, so I'm still finding out about what exceptions can occur. For now I want to stick with the `try/catch` but I do hope to negate them later on.

Comment: Tip: It is common to establish the database connection in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) so that it will be closed when the statement ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one is better, since you have `if` / `else if` statements, only one of them will be executed, and might throw an exception.So, putting the statement into a `try/catch` is more logical.In this case I can't see any advantage of using first version over to second.Your second code snippet does the same job with less code.

However, if you want to handle different exceptions on each statement then you will have to use different `try` / `catch` statements.

Comment: Since these methods are used purely for querying the Db, is there any chance I may have to deal with more than one exception?

Comment: @Ben yes, see the documentation of the method that you are using.Usually most of the methods throws more than one exception, see the Exception List in the documentation.but ofcourse in your case the other possible exceptions may not be relevant with DB...

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better.

If you are going to use several `if / else if`, it'd be a nice idea to isolate the code that will be in the part `// Query db` inside a method so you don't have to repeat your code. Then you can pass your queries a parameter of this method.